# How to effectively manage android detail navigation?

Tags: android

I am developing the detail view of a product which gives suggestions of similar products (waking the same activity with another product who also has suggestions) more or less like Google Play app detail activity. The problem comes when **accessing to multiple related products which causes a OutOfMemoryException** (since we are keeping all the previous instances of that ProductDetailActivity on the BackStack).

Is there a way of provide proper products back history without having to keep all the previous activities consuming memory?

I've checked Google play app and I'm not able to see how but it seems that it keeps all the previous activities and it's not causing any OutOfMemory while navigating related apps over related apps.

Comment: try to use fragments instead of activities, this will reduce the chance of outof memory error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue.  In my case I was using fragments, but I will share the technique so you can use it with your activity.

You can think of the multiple activities like a stack.  When the user selects a product suggestion, the current activity is pushed onto the stack and a new activity is started. Conversely, when the back button is pressed, the activity finishes and the previous activity is popped off the stack and made current.

This can consume a lot of memory depending on your application.

The insight that I had was that I could save a lot on memory by managing that stack myself, and only saving the minimum amount of data required to recreate that UI.

So let's start by creating the stack:

```
        private ArrayList<Bundle> mProductStack;
```

You will need to persist this stack in `onSaveInstanceState()` and recover it in `onCreate()`.  Let's get those out of the way:

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // ... all your other state saving code
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("productStack", mProductStack);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //  ... all your other activity create logic 
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mProductStack = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("productStack");
        } else {
            mProductStack = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

There's a reason for using a list rather than a stack.  I had a lot of problems with persisting/unpersisting a `Stack<Bundle>` around casting and so forth, so I decided to go with the simple `ArrayList<Bundle>`, which is supported directly by `Bundle` (`putParcelableArrayList()`, etc).

Now when the user navigates to a new product, you need to save the current state in the stack, and load your new product into the current activity.  Your state might even be as simple as a product ID:

```
     Bundle entry = new Bundle();
     entry.putInt("productId", mProductId);
     mProductStack.add(entry);   // push
     // ... load the data for the next product
```

You may need to persist some actual UI state, for example I had this:

```
     int scrollPos = mNestedScrollView.getScrollY();    // remember where we were in the list
     entry.putInt("scrollPos", scrollPos);
```

Now you just have to handle the back button press:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mProductStack.isEmpty()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    Bundle entry = mProductStack.remove(mProductStack.size() - 1); // pop
    mProductId= entry.getInt("productId");
    // ... load the data for the previous product
}
```

I don't know how complex your state is, but keep in mind that all the data types you want to save will need to implement `Parcelable`.  There's a lot of content online (including SO) on this topic.

The thing that seems to have the most impact on memory is images.  Memory management for bitmaps is a whole nasty topic unto itself.  You may want to implement some type of LRU cache for images so you don't have to re-fetch images for the previous product — unless memory constraints force you to do so.